# display an image when dropdown is selected

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to display an image when a dropdown is selected with the code below.By default dropdown value will be "None".Initially when the page is loaded it is not displaying image.when i select field2 or field image is diaplaying.But when i select none again the image is still diaplaying.The code i used is:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="field1" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="field2">field2</option>
<option value="field3">field3</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#image").hide();
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
   if ( this.value == 'field2') 
   {
      $("#image").show();
   }
   elsif(this.value == 'field3')
   {
       $("#image1").show();
   }
  else
   {
      $("#image").hide();
      $("#image1").hide();
   }
 });
```

});

`#image img {
    padding-left:554px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: 774px; 
  }`

Comment: if ( this.value == 'field2' || this.value == 'field3' )

Comment: Because your `if` statement is "if `this.value` is equal to `field2` *or* this string exists (which it does)..." it is *not* checking that `this.value` is equal to either `field2` or `field3`.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Use the `.indexOf()` on an array of the good values and check if the value is in the array. To ensure that the handler fires at page load trigger the `change` event with `.change()`.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
        if ( ['field2', 'field3'].indexOf( this.value ) > -1 )
        {
            $("#image").show();
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#image").hide();
        }
    })
    .change();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
   if ( ['field2', 'field3'].indexOf( this.value ) > -1 )
   {
      $("#image").show();
   }
  else 
   {
      $("#image").hide();
   }
 })
  .change();
});
```

```css
#image img {
    padding-left: 60px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: -10px; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="field1" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="field2">field2</option>
<option value="field3">field3</option>
</select>

<div id="image">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQijmYaWonPS_ckwz9WLIrMpDPWCQDOTe8D7O_RIjEVcyMKr7NwZQ" alt="some image" />
</div>
```

**Update**

*Note*: For the purpose of continuity, it is good practice to retain the original question and include any new updates. When the question is drastically different, it's advisable to create a new question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    $('#image,#image1').hide();
   if ( this.value === 'field2') 
   {
      $("#image").show();
   }
   else if(this.value === 'field3')
   {
       $("#image1").show();
   }
  else
   {
      $("#image").hide();
      $("#image1").hide();
   }
 })
  .change();
});
```

```css
#imagex img {
    padding-left:554px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: 774px; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="field1" selected="selected">None</option>
<option value="field2">field2</option>
<option value="field3">field3</option>
</select>
<span id="image">#image</span>
<span id="image1">#image1</span>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.How can i get output for the above edited question