# How to display image when a icon is selected

Tags: html, jquery

I kinda have no clue about this.

A web page starts with 8 icons. When an icon is selected, the related image will be displayed. Then, if the the icon is unselected, the image will be disappeared.

The path of the images is like

```
<img src="img/icons/image1.png" /> 
<img src="img/icons/image1.png" />
```

Also I tried to use code from [display an image when dropdown is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538872/display-an-image-when-dropdown-is-selected), it is related but I still cannot solve it.

I hope the pictures help explain my question.

**start like this:**

[image: start like this]

**click icon 1:**

[image: click icon 1]

**click icon 2:**

[image: click icon 2]

If icon2 is clicked again, it will go back to 2nd pic

Comment: If you want something to happen when the user clicks an icon, you need to add a click handler to that icon. What is your HTML? Where is your code that creates a click handler?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <img src="img/icons/image1.png" onclick="img_show(1)">
 <img src="img/icons/image1.png" onclick="img_show(2)">
 <img src="img/icons/image1.png" onclick="img_show(3)">  

 <img src="image1.png" id="image1" >
 <img src="image2.png" id="image2" >
 <img src="image3.png" id="image3" >


  <script>
     function img_show(id){
        if(id ==1){
           $("#image1").show();
           $("#image2").hide();
           $("#image3").hide();
         }
         else if(id==2){
           $("#image1").hide();
           $("#image2").show();
           $("#image3").hide();
        }
          else if(id==3){
           $("#image1").hide();
           $("#image2").hide();
           $("#image3").show();
        }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do like this:

 <img src="image/icon1.png" onclick="showImage(1)">
 <img src="image/icon2.png" onclick="showImage(2)">
 <img src="image/icon3.png" onclick="showImage(3)">  

<!--by default set img1-->
 <img src="img1.png" id="image">

     <script>
         function showImage(item){
            if(item == 1){
              $("#image").attr("src","image/img1.png");
             }
            if(item  == 2){
               $("#image").attr("src","image/img2.png");
            }
            if(item == 3){
              $("#image").attr("src","image/img3.png");
            }
          }
    </script>
```